# Karate retry logic - call another feature if condition fails

Tags: api, automation, karate, intuit-partner-platform, retry-logic

I am very new to Karate. I am trying to use the retry logic.I have posted the code I tried below. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance .

Step1 : I want to check if the response actualNo == expectedNo

Step2  : If actualNo not equal to expectedNo, script  has to call the CallWait.feature,wait for 30 seconds and then check if the response has the expected value .

Step3: If actualNo == expectedNo , then print success message and come out of retry , else come out of retry with a failure message

Code :
And retry until (response.actualNo==expectedNo) || karate.call('classpath:com/sample/test/setup/CallWait.feature') {waitDuration: #(waitTime)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for "conditional logic" please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

But if you want such fine-grained control over your re-try loop, just write your logic in JS and refer the first `Scenario` of this example: [`polling.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature)